# Inequality involving the Hessian matrix of a convex function

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, hessian-matrix

Let $f \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be a convex function with Hessian $H$.
Is it true that
$$
(x^T H(x) - y^T H(y)) (x-y) \ge 0 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)
$$
for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^d$?

$$
~
$$
I noticed that
$$
(x^T H(x) - y^T H(y)) (x-y) = \begin{bmatrix}x & y \end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} H(x) & - H(x) \\ -H(y) & H(y) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}
$$
and that
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix} H(x) & - H(x) \\ -H(y) & H(y) \end{bmatrix} = 0.
$$
Maybe this is helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your favourite, convex, smooth function $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f''(2) = 1$ and $f''(1) = 3$.

Then, with $x = 2$ and $y = 1$ we get
$$(x \, f''(x) - y \, f''(y)) \, (x - y) = (2 \cdot 1 - 1 \cdot 3) \, (2 - 1) = - 1 < 0.$$

A final note: If you need to determine the sign of something like $x^\top A \, x$, you have to study the eigenvalues of $(A + A^\top)/2$ and not those of $A$. Note that $x^\top A \, x = x^\top (A + A^\top)/2 \, x$.

Comment: Thank you! I will have to find some additional conditions for $f$

Comment: I think you need something beyond convexity. Using convexity, you only get the semidefiniteness of the Hessian, but no further relation between $H(x)$ and $H(y)$.